# AngularJS complex table header

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm developing Timesheet application. I have ready layout (html/css). Currently I'm working on layout behavior. My current goal is extracting timesheet table header in directive. Angular template html should look similar to this:

```
<colgroup class="col_day">
    <col ng-repeat="day in header.days" ng-class="someConditions">
</colgroup>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="day in header.days" ng-class="someConditions">
            {{someLayout}}
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

I want to use this template via directive like this:

```
<table>
    <timesheet-header></timesheet-header>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Problems:

- Angular doesn't allow to use multiple roots in template in directives
  with **replace: true**
- Template content appears outside of  tag (only if template contains single  tag it is rendered inside table

I have only bad solutions:

- Create two different directives for colgroup and thead (this solves
  multiple roots, but html will still appear outside table tag)
- keep template binding results invisible and prepend copy of generated
  html to table (by jquery)
- use the directive as attribute for table tag... I tried but this
  removes all other table content (I tried transclude)...

**Note:** I'm using AngularJS v1.4.3. Debugging in latest Google Chrome.

Comment: Are you sure that when you create two different directives, the HTML contents of these directives appear outside the `table` tag?

Comment: Yep, I tried multiple times. I even tried to simplify my template to pure single-tag html. Only <tr> tag appears inside <table>. All other tags (single <colgroup>  or single <thead>) appear outside <table> (before).

Comment: I feel like an attribute directive with transclude is the right answer here. Can you give me a little more information about what was happening when you tried that?

Comment: Before there was a big angular controller and extensive html. I started pulling parts of the code to separate directive and faced with the described problem. When I try to use Element-Directive inside <table> the template html is pushed out of the <table>. Feel free to request any details you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the attribute directive was in fact the right way to go, it just took a little bit to realize how the changes to transclude work in newer versions of Angular.

So, with the newer versions of Angular, ng-transclude actually removes everything inside of the directive. It turns out though that when you use the transclude option on your directive, Angular actually exposes a function to you in the link function that allows you to manually handle the transcluded content. Once you have this, you can tell it to simply append the content instead of replace it like it does by default.

Some good reading on the subject can be found here: http://ng.malsup.com/#!/transclude-function

template:

```
<table>
  <colgroup class="col_day">
      <col ng-repeat="day in header.days" ng-class="someConditions">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th ng-repeat="day in header.days" ng-class="someConditions">
              {{someLayout}}
          </th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

directive:

```
app.directive('timesheetHeader', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'timesheet-header.template.html',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
      var transcludedContent = transcludeFn();
      el.append( transcludedContent );
    }
  };
});
```

Actual HTML Code:

```
<table timesheet-header>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td>world!</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your great answer! It works fine for me now. I'm going to add some angular directives inside trunscluded content, hope it will work =)

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

"Create two different directives for colgroup and thead (this solves multiple roots, but html will still appear outside table tag)" - You can find more details for this behavior in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459. And specifically in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459#issuecomment-67235182

You can solve this issue using transclude and custom directive for table as **attribute**

http://plnkr.co/edit/8JptrwUcA0pPl9xB9yZQ?p=preview

```
<table my-table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

.directive('myTable', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
     template: '<table>' +
              '<colgroup class="col_day"><col ng-repeat="n in [1, 2] track by $index">{{n}}</col></colgroup>' +
               '<thead>' +
                  '<tr>' +
                    '<th ng-repeat="n in [1, 2] track by $index"> {{n}}</th>' +
                  '</tr>' +
                '</thead>' +
                '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
            '</table>'
      };
  }])
```